# html5 video player with simplest controls (only play and pause)

Tags: html, jquery, video, html5-video

Somehow, there are really little tutorials out there for html5 video and audio playback.

I simply want to embed video and audio files with customized controls. However, the controls should be fairly simple. I only need a play-button. If clicked, play gets replaced by pause.
That's all!

However, I even don't know how to embed/display a video without “preload controls”. Somehow, if I only set  (without preload controls) Firefox doesn't even show anything. Chrome does show a black window.

I would love to be able to use jQuery to control the video play and pause button. Maybe you have some little start-approach for me!

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's basically all stated here: [HTML 5 video custom controls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2107354/html-5-video-custom-controls)

Answer (score 1):

There's an article co-written by one of the authors (Bruce Lawson) of the above article which, if you scroll down to, shows you how to create your own controls: [Introduction to HTML5 video](http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/introduction-html5-video/).

Answer (score -4):

You can do:

```
$('video').trigger('play');
$('video').trigger('pause');
```

For more: https://web.archive.org/web/20150411142822/http://wonderdesigners.com/?p=219

Comment: Link redirects to a strange site.