# Customize media player in HTML5

Tags: html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [HTML 5 video custom controls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2107354/html-5-video-custom-controls)

Hi,

Is it possible to customize media controls like design as well as coding? apply our own skinning and track events when touching media controllers (Play, stop, ..etc)

Thanks in Advance,

Sri

Comment: Appears to be duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2107354/html-5-video-custom-controls

Answer (score 1):

Yes, by having interface elements call the `video` object's methods.

The site http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/video.html#media-elements specifies the HTMLMediaElement interface.(the important attributes and methods are after the `//playback state` comment).

Basically

```
  el.play(); //and
  el.pause();
```

is enough to make a simple player.