# Modify default HTML5 video controls

Tags: javascript, custom-controls, html5-video

I have a rather unusual question for you all; it might be foolish but I am new to this area and I would really appreciate some help.

As the title suggests I was wondering if there is a way to disable a specific button from the default browser controls for the `HTML5` video.

I know that each browser has its own somewhat unique looking set of controls so I don't think that I can overlay the button with `CSS`.
If it is impossible is it maybe possible to somehow tie via `Javascript` the event of the video going full screen to another event?

I was looking into making the custom controls or using the pre-made players but if at all possible I would like to get away without using either.

I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't hide specific native controls. You can either use them or hide them via the [controls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2107354/html-5-video-custom-controls) attribute.

As far as using listening to fullscreen events along with other events the video API provides, [longtail](http://www.longtailvideo.com/html5/) does extensive research on compatibilities or lack thereof within different browsers and devices.

You can make your own css controls on top of the video element and control different actions via the [html5 media api](http://www.w3.org/2010/05/video/mediaevents.html) demonstrated here.

For fullscreen type things, I'd recommend looking through the code [here](https://github.com/bdougherty/BigScreen) as it was written for the Vimeo HTML5 player specifically.

It's kind of a nightmare dealing with the Video API depending how much support you're trying to achieve.