# HTML5 video and current time at ie10

Tags: html, internet-explorer, html5-video

instead of showing the remaining time i always see -30s.
as you can see with the image attached[image]

Any ideas how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

This button is for skipping 30 seconds before current play time. If you want to display elapsed time you need to implement your own controls. This question will guide you -> [HTML 5 video custom controls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2107354/html-5-video-custom-controls)

Comment: thanks for that. do you have any idea how to cancel this button?

Comment: I think that you can't disable it in default player. You can override controls building custom ones.